XSLT 3.0 Grouping by <xsl:function as="xs:boolean">: How to map result to meaningful text attributes for output
I want to use my own <xsl:function> as a grouping key in XSLT 3.0. My function returns xs:boolean but in the output of the grouping I want to map true and false to meaningful string values, in my case true = 'Live album' and false = 'Studio album'.
My first attempts with using an if..else-expression or outsorucing current-grouping-key() to a local variable all failed syntactically.
This is my stylesheet:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="https://my-function.library.org" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:function name="my:group-key" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="recording"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="contains($recording/title, 'Live')"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <groups>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="recording" group-by="my:group-key(.)">
                <group key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <titel><xsl:value-of select="title"/></titel>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </groups>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

and this is the input XML (excerpt):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <recording medium="LP" state="2" no="1">
        <title>The Years 1960-1970</title>
        (...)
    </recording>
    
    <recording medium="tape" state="6" no="2">
        <title>Live at the Village Vanguard</title>
        (...)
    </recording>
    
    <recording medium="CD" state="8" no="3">
        <title>Classic Tunes</title>
        (...)
    </recording>
</catalog>

The desired output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups>
    <group key="Studio album">
        <titel>The Years 1960-1970</titel>
        <titel>Classic Tunes</titel>
    </group>
    <group key="Live album">
        <titel>Live at the Village Vanguard</titel>
    </group>
</groups>

Ideally I want to have a general solution that would allow for more mappings than just for true and false. So an if..else-based solution would not even be ideal.
I was also wondering if it would make sense to outsource this mapping to a separate function. Any opinions about best practices here are also welcome.

If the function returns a boolean value why would you need a general mapping for more than just true and false? Anyway, XSLT 3.0 has XDM 3.1 maps e.g. <xsl:param name="my-map" as="map(xs:boolean, xs:string)" select="map { true() : 'Live album', false() : 'Studio album' }"/> and then you can use $my-map(current-grouping-key()).

Great, thank you @MartinHonnen, works!
This is indeed the more general solution I hoped for. While my function returns xs:boolean, in a different scenario, I might want perhaps numerical values to be mapped. The state of each recording for example could be used to be mapped to strings for readable output.
Then of course it might make more sense to have the original function return the strings directly. This is what I achieved while experimenting with your suggested solution: I used your <xsl_param> as an xsl:variable inside the function and returned 'Live ' or 'Studio ' directlly. Thx!

I don't see why you need the boolean, why not map the input directly to the output form?
<xsl:function name="my:group-key" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="recording"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="if (contains($recording/title, 'Live')) 
                          then 'Live album' 
                          else 'Studio album'"/>
</xsl:function>


Great, thank you! Now I have another syntactic variant. While I prefer the map-based solution by @MartinHonnen for its more general approach, this comes as valuable input for my current learning efforts.
It's good to know for me right now, being under such time pressure, that you and Martin are around. Couldn't wish for more. Thank you!

For anybody looking for runnable code ready for copy&pasting, this is my final solution:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="https://my-function.library.org" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:function name="my:group-key" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="recording"/>
        <xsl:variable name="my-map" as="map(xs:boolean, xs:string)" select="map { true() : 'Live album', false() : 'Studio album' }"/> 
        <xsl:sequence select="$my-map(contains($recording/title, 'Live'))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <groups>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="recording" group-by="my:group-key(.)">
                
                <group key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <titel><xsl:value-of select="title"/></titel>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </groups>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Thanx @MartinHonnen for the inspiration!
